# UI/UX when showing a ton of data on a small mobile device

Tags: tables, mobile-application, info-visualisation, data-tables, charts

I need to show a ton of data and make it look good.

Heres my current list view:

[image: Current]

Heres what i think is "nicer":

[image]

And heres another idea with table switches:

[image]

Some guidance is appreciated. Im learning the front end from a more backend background ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would avoid using the same typographic variable for statement and
  content. The statements are repeated, so a round font is not
  necessary nor is it extremely legible; on the contrary, a bold/condensed one recovers space and offers better visibility to the response in a light/round font.
  ([Saira Extra Condensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Saira+Extra+Condensed?query=conden) in the example)
- When using capital letters for statements, one or two pixels below the size of the answers offer the same visual perception and provide space.
- If necessary, differentiate both elements by color.
- A table-type layout allows the user to find elements easily.

[image]

Comment: Great answer, and thank you for the help. This is a beautiful solution. I might stray from that much of a condensed font because at first glance its slightly harder to read, from a user stand point. Everything else you mention helps my situation in very strategic and subtle ways but makes a big impact. Can you recommend another font or help the readability of the questions slightly? Maybe I can try slightly less bolding? Will test this out tomorrow :)

Comment: Just type "condensed" in the Google Fonts search bar.